# Automatic Mix software to replace a DJ

Tags: mixing, software, recommendations

Since there are a lot of audio fans here, do you know a good software to replace a DJ in a private office party? The direction is tired of hiring a (bad) DJ year after year when what people really want is to hear songs they like with minimal mixing between the tracks.

Here is what is needed in your answer:

1. Software that take the tempo of each song into account to make the mix
2. Fade-out / fade-in between the track should not be the only mixing feature.
3. Can be a plugin or a standalone application.
4. Possibility to change songs order in the play list in real time (By this, it means the mix will not be "pre-recorded", it will be done live by the software)

EDIT: If it's free, it's even better but this is not needed.

Comment: Why does your company keep hiring bad DJs?

Comment: @ObscureRobot: This is totaly out of my control, but it's a fact...

Comment: @ObscureRobot's question is quite on topic. This is a terrible question (at least iMO) because any DJ (even a low talented one such as myself) should have all of these skills. If not then he is not a disc jockey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a bit like a shopping question, but the only one I know that does this is [MixMeister](http://www.mixmeister.com/products_mmexp7.html).

It can do all 4 of your requirements:

1. Beat matching and transition throughout
2. Fade out/in and use of effects
3. Is a standalone application
4. Can add to the playlist in real time, run from existing playlist, or both

Comment: Thanks for the info. Seems like a good product. I will wait a couple of days to see if other solution comes out.

Comment: For future reference: The name is MixMeister and can be reached right at http://www.mixmeister.com/

Answer (score 2):

[VirtualDJ](http://www.virtualdj.com/) also does all this, and comes in a free addition as well.

From the website:

> Designed for home DJs, VirtualDJ Home includes nearly all the features
>   of VirtualDJ Pro, with only a few limitations. If you don't own or
>   don't plan to use any additional DJ hardware (mixer, turntable, DJ
>   controller or video projector), then VirtualDJ Home will meet all your
>   requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You might like djay, check out http://www.algoriddim.com/djay